# OnMapReadyCallback has an error when im trying to implement it and the getMapAsync is undefined for the type MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps

This is my first time asking here and im a beginner in android can anybody tell me why does OnMapReadyCallback has an error when im trying to implement it and the getMapAsync is undefined for the type MapFragment.. what does that suppose to mean? im using eclipse and im trying to use Google Maps Api V2 on android.. i was just following the steps in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map but i still have some errors.. can somebody help me fix it? Thank you!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;``

public class FirstScreen extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps you have an older version of the Play Services SDK attached to your project. `getMapAsync()` was added a month or two ago.

Comment: @CommonsWare There is no update needed in my SDK manager. Thank you for trying to help me sir/maam!

Comment: What is in your SDK Manager is only part of the issue. Since you are using Eclipse, it is the *copy* of the Play Services SDK that your project is referencing that matters.

Comment: @CommonsWare It seems that i have to update my eclipse so i can see if there are updates needed in SDK manager. Anyway Thank you so much sir/maam!

Comment: I am having the same issue.  What is the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

your class should extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`